# How to reset_index when mapping excel sheet in a loop using pandas in Python 3.0?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, loops, oop

I am facing a little issue while working with pandas and reset_index function.
Below is the excel and 3 sheet I am trying to map.

[image: INFORMATION SOURCE SHEET]

[image: INFORMATION RECEIVER SHEET]

[image]

Please find the code below :

```
filename='C:\\HPTiB\\HPTib_Test_Cases\\template_276.xlsx'
data=pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name=['INFORMATION SOURCE','INFORMATION RECEIVER','SERVICE PROVIDER'],dtype=str)
sequence=0
segments_276=[]
N_info_src=len(data['INFORMATION SOURCE'])
N_info_recv=len(data['INFORMATION RECEIVER'])
N_svc_prv=len(data['SERVICE PROVIDER'])
N_sub=len(data['SUBSCRIBER'])

for i in range(N_info_src):

    print("Value of i",i)
    #Currently iterating over the info source loop
    sequence=sequence+1
    source_parent=sequence
    #Write the HL segment
    segments_276.append('HL*'+str(sequence)+'**20*1')

    #Write all the loop segments for this row
 #   loop_segments=Parser.build_loop('2100A',i,data['INFORMATION SOURCE'])
 #   segments_276=segments_276+loop_segments
    #Get the KEY for this info source and related keys in the next table

    SOURCE_KEY=data['INFORMATION SOURCE'].loc[i,'SOURCE KEY']
    subset_info_recv=data['INFORMATION RECEIVER'][data['INFORMATION RECEIVER']['SOURCE KEY']==SOURCE_KEY]
    #Reset index to avoid key errors
    subset_info_recv.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    N_info_recv=len(subset_info_recv)

    for j in range(N_info_recv):

        print("value of j \n {} and value of subset_info_recv \n {}".format(j,subset_info_recv))
        #Currently itesrating over the info recv loop
        sequence=sequence+1
        recv_parent=sequence
        #Write the HL segment
#        segments_276.append('HL*'+str(sequence)+'*'+str(source_parent)+'*21*1')
        #Write all the loop segments for this row
#        loop_segments=Parser.build_loop('2100B',j,subset_info_recv)
#        segments_276=segments_276+loop_segment

    # Get the KEY for this info receiver and related keys in the next table
        RECEIVER_KEY = data['INFORMATION RECEIVER'].loc[j, 'RECEIVER KEY']
        subset_info_provider = data['SERVICE PROVIDER'][data['SERVICE PROVIDER']['RECEIVER KEY'] == RECEIVER_KEY]

    # Reset index to avoid key errors
        subset_info_provider.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        N_svc_prv = len(subset_info_provider)
        print("Lengh of provider sheet", N_svc_prv)

        for k in range(N_svc_prv):

            print("value of k \n {} and value of subset_info_provider \n {}".format(k,subset_info_provider))

        # Currently iterating over the info Provider loop
            sequence = sequence + 1
            provider_parent = sequence

        # Write the HL segment
            segments_276.append('HL*' + str(sequence) + '*' + str(recv_parent) + '*19*1')

        #Write all the loop segments for this row
            #print("Value of k {} and \n subset_info_provider \n {} ".format(k,subset_info_provider))
#            loop_segments=Parser.build_loop('2100C',k,subset_info_provider)
#            segments_276=segments_276+loop_segments

#Print the result
#for segment in segments_276:
#    print(segment)
```

OUTPUT :

```
Value of i 0
value of j  0 
and value of subset_info_recv 
   SOURCE KEY RECEIVER KEY RECIEVER KEY TYPE RECIEVER NAME RECIEVER CODE
0          1            1            PERSON           CEO    A222222221
1          1            2            PERSON    CO-FOUNDER    A222222221

value of k  0 
and value of subset_info_provider 
   RECEIVER KEY PROVIDER KEY PROVIDER NAME PROVIDER ID TYPE PROVIDER ID
0            1            1         Tesla  Provider Number   123456789
1            1            2         Apple              TIN   123453234

value of k  1 
and value of subset_info_provider 
   RECEIVER KEY PROVIDER KEY PROVIDER NAME PROVIDER ID TYPE PROVIDER ID
0            1            1         Tesla  Provider Number   123456789
1            1            2         Apple              TIN   123453234

value of j  1 
and value of subset_info_recv 
   SOURCE KEY RECEIVER KEY RECIEVER KEY TYPE RECIEVER NAME RECIEVER CODE
0          1            1            PERSON           CEO    A222222221
1          1            2            PERSON    CO-FOUNDER    A222222221

value of k  0 
and value of subset_info_provider 
   RECEIVER KEY PROVIDER KEY PROVIDER NAME PROVIDER ID TYPE PROVIDER ID
0            2            3     Microsoft              NPI   123453756

Value of i 1
value of j  0 
and value of subset_info_recv 
   SOURCE KEY RECEIVER KEY RECIEVER KEY TYPE RECIEVER NAME RECIEVER CODE
0          2            3            PERSON           CFO    A222222221

value of k  0 
and value of subset_info_provider 
   RECEIVER KEY PROVIDER KEY PROVIDER NAME PROVIDER ID TYPE PROVIDER ID
0            1            1         Tesla  Provider Number   123456789
1            1            2         Apple              TIN   123453234

value of k  1 
and value of subset_info_provider 
   RECEIVER KEY PROVIDER KEY PROVIDER NAME PROVIDER ID TYPE PROVIDER ID
0            1            1         Tesla  Provider Number   123456789
1            1            2         Apple              TIN   123453234
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Value of i 0
value of j  0 
and value of subset_info_recv 
   SOURCE KEY RECEIVER KEY RECIEVER KEY TYPE RECIEVER NAME RECIEVER CODE
0          1            1            PERSON           CEO    A222222221
1          1            2            PERSON    CO-FOUNDER    A222222221


value of k  0 
and value of subset_info_provider 
   RECEIVER KEY PROVIDER KEY PROVIDER NAME PROVIDER ID TYPE PROVIDER ID
0            1            1         Tesla  Provider Number   123456789
1            1            2         Apple              TIN   123453234

value of k  1 
and value of subset_info_provider 
   RECEIVER KEY PROVIDER KEY PROVIDER NAME PROVIDER ID TYPE PROVIDER ID
0            1            1         Tesla  Provider Number   123456789
1            1            2         Apple              TIN   123453234

value of j  1 
and value of subset_info_recv 
   SOURCE KEY RECEIVER KEY RECIEVER KEY TYPE RECIEVER NAME RECIEVER CODE
0          1            1            PERSON           CEO    A222222221
1          1            2            PERSON    CO-FOUNDER    A222222221

value of k  0 
and value of subset_info_provider 
   RECEIVER KEY PROVIDER KEY PROVIDER NAME PROVIDER ID TYPE PROVIDER ID
0            2            3     Microsoft              NPI   123453756

Value of i 1
value of j  0 
and value of subset_info_recv 
   SOURCE KEY RECEIVER KEY RECIEVER KEY TYPE RECIEVER NAME RECIEVER CODE
0          2            3            PERSON           CFO    A222222221

value of k  0 
and value of subset_info_provider 
   RECEIVER KEY PROVIDER KEY PROVIDER NAME PROVIDER ID TYPE PROVIDER ID
0            3            4         Google  Provider Number   675453756
```

SO , if you see in OUTPUT for Service provider sheet , it is not printing the value of  RECEIVER KEY 3 , 
instead it is getting reset and printing first two values.

Could you please help me point out the issue , am I not looping it correctly?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```py
RECEIVER_KEY = data['INFORMATION RECEIVER'].loc[j, 'RECEIVER KEY']
```

to

```py
RECEIVER_KEY = subset_info_recv.loc[j, 'RECEIVER KEY']
```

because the `for` loop of `j` are in `range(len(subset_info_recv))`.

Comment: Thank you Gorisanson , I was stuck for hours on it !!